# Chromecast testing for playable content receiver side

Tags: chromecast

In the javascript api for HTML5 video there is a canPlayType method to check if something is playable or not. However I've noticed that on the Chromecast this function doesn't quite cover everything. On several occasions playing local content with the app I'm working on I'll get an error saying that it is not playable, but if I take off my error checking which uses canPlayType then I have no issues. I'm curious if anyone has nailed down a good way to figure out supported content other than simply checking strings against a list that we create using the supported media types from https://developers.google.com/cast/supported_media_types

Comment: Could you include a couple of examples that you ran into issues with?

Comment: One example that I can give you right now, and I can track down more, is that this file http://mirrorblender.top-ix.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/big_buck_bunny_1080p_h264.mov will play but comes back as unplayable. I've also seen other files in the .mkv container that will play as well.

Comment: When you say it comes back as not playable, what is the return value of that method?

Comment: I'm getting back empty string. Been following this documentation for the api https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement — is there a chrome version of this kinda of documentation?

Answer (score 0):

The response to HTMLMediaElement.canPlayType()is supposed to be accurate and reliable. If you see any inaccuracy there on Chromecast devices, please file a bug with the appropriate information, thanks.

Comment: Is that method available in IOS sdk too?

Comment: If not, how can I check if a media is not supported?

Comment: The canPlayTypes() is on the receiver side and is not available on the sender. The list of supported media formats is available at https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/media

Comment: I see but when I send to the Chromecast a MKV/WMA files then sends me back the disconnect event. It should not play or play next file instead disconnection.

Comment: Roku for example skips the unknown media file and plays the next one, same should behave Chromecast 1 and 2

Comment: If you have a technical question, please ask that here otherwise this is not a forum to discuss whether a certain product should or should behave in a certain way.

Comment: We understand your point of view but the Chromecast crash and disconnect is still present for unknown media type.